# (Django app) Why is it that the same comment on a post is appearing once for every like it receives from a user?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am currently making a Reddit-style app / site using Django in Gitpod as a project for a diploma-level portfolio course I am doing. I'm not an advanced programmer / web developer at all, so this project isn't anywhere close to the complexity of Reddit, but it's basically just a super-super-lite version of it. A list of posts is displayed on the home page, and if you click into one, you are taken to a page for that post, where you can read anything that the poster wrote themselves, as well as any comments that were left below the post.

For the posts and the comments, there is a primitive like/unlike button. As mentioned in the title, it is the like button for comments that is buggy, and I'm just about ready to give up trying to fix it. On the surface, the issue is this: If the comment has 0 likes, and one user likes it, the number ticks up to 1 - the expected behaviour - but if another user comes along and likes it as well, the number ticks up to 2, and the comment is displayed *twice* on the page. Both copies of this comment have two likes each. If a third user adds a like, a third copy of the comment appears, and so on.

Each comment is based on the Comment model in models.py, and the likes field of this model is a many-to-many field that is linked to the User model in Django's built-in authentication system.

The appearance of the like button depends on whether the user clicking it can be found in the likes for that comment. If they can't, the button appears unclicked (grey), and if they can, it appears clicked (green). Either way, the button is within a form, and if it is clicked, a view executes, and by using print statements, it seems that the comment is duplicated after this line executes: `comment.likes.add(request.user)` (where 'comment' is the comment whose like button was clicked).

I thought maybe that this was an *event* issue - that a submit or click event was firing twice - but I tried all that I know how to do with JavaScript / jQuery (the disable property, preventDefault, .one, and more), and none of it changed anything. Moreover, from using logs to the console, it doesn't seem like any of said events are firing twice, anyway.

On top of this, the add method above also only executes once per click (according to print statements, of which only one set was logged to the terminal per click), so it can't really be that the view is executing twice (from two submits of the form).

From my very limited perspective, the only concrete thing that seems to remain is the template for the page where the comments are displayed. I was wondering if it had something to do with the for loop that iterates through the post's comments and displays each one, but I can't quite figure out how that would be the case. As far as I can tell, there's nothing wrong with the logic within the for loop either.

So, it does seem like it has to have something to do with the add method that is used with ManyToManyFields. I'm wondering if I perhaps just don't fully understand how it works and am misusing it. The thing is though, I'm basically copying the code from the walkthrough project that was covered as part of this course, so I don't understand why it's behaving so differently in my own.

I should also add that the home page (index.html) template also iterates through posts, and displays them Reddit-style. The view in this case is a ListView, but otherwise, the template still uses a for loop, and more importantly, each post has a functioning like button that does *not* cause the posts to be duplicated on the page. The Bulletin model is used for posts, and it too has a *likes* many-to-many field that is linked to the User model. The view that controls likes for posts uses the same logic as the view that controls likes for comments, i.e. it uses the add and remove methods - `bulletin.likes.add(request.user)`, but functions exactly how I want it to. So I'm really just at a complete loss, here. It almost seems like a browser bug, or an IDE bug, but realistically, I'm not experienced or knowledgeable enough for this to be anything other than a mistake in my code or misuse of some construct or other.

If you've gotten this far, thanks! You might already have some idea of what's wrong, but I'll share the relevant code below:

The Comment model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    bulletin = models.ForeignKey(Bulletin, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                 related_name='comments_on_post')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               related_name='comments_by_user')
    comment = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='comment_likes')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Comment: "{self.comment}", by {self.author}'

    def number_of_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()
```

The CommentLike view in views.py:

```
class CommentLike(View):
    def post(self, request, slug, *args, **kwargs):
        bulletin_queryset = Bulletin.objects.filter(status=1)
        bulletin = get_object_or_404(bulletin_queryset, slug=slug)

        comments = bulletin.comments_on_post.order_by('likes')
        query = request.GET.get('query')
        comment = get_object_or_404(comments, id=query)

        if comment.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            comment.likes.remove(request.user)
        else:
            comment.likes.add(request.user)

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('bulletin', args=[slug]))
```

The BulletinDetail view that displays the individual post's page and its comments (post method omitted). The above view redirects to this:

```
class BulletinDetail(View):
    def get(self, request, slug, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = Bulletin.objects.filter(status=1)
        bulletin = get_object_or_404(queryset, slug=slug)
        comments = bulletin.comments_on_post.order_by('likes')

        return render(
            request,
            'bulletin.html',
            {
                'bulletin': bulletin,
                'comments': comments,
                'comment_form': CommentForm()
            },
        )
```

Comment for-loop in *bulletin.html*, which is the template used for individual posts and their respective comments (I hope this is readable; it looks messy in this text box, so I spaced it out a bit):

```
{% for comment in comments %}
<div class="row my-5">
    <div class="col-12">

        <div class="card">

            {% if comment.author == request.user and user.is_authenticated %}

            <div class="card-header green-header">

                <h2 class="d-inline">{{ comment.author }}</h2>

                <form class="float-end" method="POST" action="{% url 'delete_request' bulletin.slug %}?query={{ comment.id }}"> 

                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg float-end delete-bulletin-button">Delete</button>

                </form>

                <a href="{% url 'comment_edit' bulletin.slug %}?query={{ comment.id }}" class="float-end btn btn-lg edit-bulletin-button me-2">Edit</a>

            </div>

            {% else %}

            <div class="card-header">
                <h2 class="d-inline">{{ comment.author }}</h2>
            </div>

            {% endif %}

            <div class="card-body"> <!-- This is the container used for each comment -->
                
                <p class="float-start">{{ comment.comment }}</p>

                {% if user.is_authenticated %}

                <form method="POST"
                    action="{% url 'comment_like' bulletin.slug %}?query={{ comment.id }}"
                    class="d-inline like-button-form" id="comment-like-form-{{ comment.id }}">

                    {% csrf_token %}

                    {% if request.user not in comment.likes.all %}

                    <button type="button" name="comment_id" class="btn float-end" id="comment-not-liked-{{ comment.id }}">{{ comment.number_of_likes }}<i class="far fa-thumbs-up not-liked-by-user ms-1"></i></button>

                    {% else %}

                    <button type="button" name="comment_id" class="btn float-end" id="comment-liked-{{ comment.id }}">{{ comment.number_of_likes }}<i class="fas fa-thumbs-up liked-by-user ms-2"></i></button>

                    {% endif %}

                </form>

                {% else %}

                <button type="button" class="btn text-secondary float-end like-button">{{ comment.number_of_likes }}<i class="far fa-thumbs-up ms-2"></i></button>

                {% endif %}  

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Anyway, I know this might be too long of a question, but I feel like I've done my best trying to figure this out, and I only have so much time to finish this project (March 19th is the deadline). I can provide the code for other parts of it if needed. I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me out.

Comment: What happens if you remove `.order_by('likes')`?

Comment: @Marco: No change, unfortunately, unless there's something else I need to do in conjunction with that. I do want the comment with the most likes to be displayed at the top, though.